# Creating Register Set Values in a PCB class

Tags: java, operating-system

Part of my assignment for my OS class requires me to create a Process Control Block class in Java with various fields. I've already created the class with all the different fields, such as name, state, arrival time, etc. However when asked to do this I'm stuck:

- register set values (an object of a class “RegisterSet” containing the following fields: XAR, XDI, XDO, PC, IR, EMIT, RR, PSW, R0, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7).

It seems like I have to create another class called RegisterSet, with all those various fields, however I'm stuck on just how I"m supposed to do that, and then how to create the set values in my PCB class...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have. I have the RegisterSet class with setters and getters for each Register and then in my PCB class I have a setValues function which looks like this:

```
public void setValues(String XAR,
                        String XDO, String PC, String IR,
                        String EMIT, String RR, String PSW,
                        String R0, String R1, String R2,
                        String R3, String R4, String R5, String R6,
                        String R7){
    RegisterSet reg = new RegisterSet();
    reg.setXAR(XAR);
    reg.setXDO(XDO);
    reg.setPC(PC);
    reg.setIR(IR);
    reg.setEMIT(EMIT);
    reg.setRR(RR);
    reg.setPSW(PSW);
    reg.setR0(R0);
    reg.setR1(R1);
    reg.setR2(R2);
    reg.setR3(R3);
    reg.setR4(R4);
    reg.setR5(R5);
    reg.setR6(R6);
    reg.setR7(R7);
}
```

Then I have the getValues method which runs a ToString() that I made in the RegisterSet class:

```
public String getValues(){
    RegisterSet reg = new RegisterSet();
    return reg.ToString();
}
```

And finally, here is what I am trying to run in my sim:

```
//Remaining are Registers
String xar = st.nextToken();
String xdi = st.nextToken();
String xdo = st.nextToken();
String pc = st.nextToken();
String ir = st.nextToken();
String emit = st.nextToken();
String rr = st.nextToken();
String psw = st.nextToken();
String r0 = st.nextToken();
String r1 = st.nextToken();
String r2 = st.nextToken();
String r3 = st.nextToken();
String r4 = st.nextToken();
String r5 = st.nextToken();
String r6 = st.nextToken();
String r7 = st.nextToken();
PCB.setValues(xar, xdi, xdo, pc, ir, emit, rr, psw,
        r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7);
```

The error I get when I try to compile says this:

```
 required:     String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String
 found: String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Basically, I am reading in different details from many processes, filling the data into a PCB, and then adding the PCB into a Process Table, which is really just an ArrayList. After that I iterate through the ArrayList, and print out each process.

Comment: Post some of your code/classes and we might be able to see where your errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
class PCB {
    ...
    RegisterSet registerSet = new RegisterSet();

    public RegisterSet getRegisterSet() { return this.registerSet; }
    public void setRegisterSet(RegisterSet rs) { this.registerSet = rs; }
    ...
}
```

This answers your direct question, but somehow I'm not sure this what you meant to ask.

Comment: Well I have my own RegisterSet class with setters/getters for each Register. Then, in the PCB class I have a function called setValues that goes and sets the values for each register. THen, in my simulation, I run the PCB.setValues(xar, xdi, xdo, etc.) but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: What is the error? Update your post and add the COMPLETE stack trace.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding some basics.  Your `getValues()` creates a new, _empty_ `RegisterSet` object, executes its `toString()` method and returns the result, which is not what you want.  As to the error, you forgot to include `XDI` in the definition of `setValues()`.  The error is telling you you provided too many arguments to the method call.

Comment: Hmm yea you're right. When I try to run it, I get all Null values for each Register. Do you see what I am trying to do though? I want to call the getValues() method and be able to print them based off that.

Comment: You need to read up on class members.  In your `setValues()` you are creating a new `RegisterSet` but not saving it anywhere, so as soon as `setValues()` completes, the `RegisterSet` object is discarded.  Look carefully at the code in my answer above for the correct way to define, set and retrieve a `RegisterSet` member in your `PCB` class.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I need to declare my RegisterSet member outside the function, where I define all my other variables. That way I can keep the data in there. My only problem now is trying to figure out how to get the Register Values to print.